# Laravel 5.6 Dependency injection through parameter id

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.6

I have a route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {

    Route::resource('photos', 'Admin\PhotoController', [
        'parameters' => [
            'photos' => 'alias'
        ]
]);
```

});

command php artisan route:list:
[image]

With command:

php artisan make:controller Admin/PhotoController --resource --model=Models/Photo

I created resource controller Admin/PhotoController, that has a method

```
    public function edit(Photo $photo)
    {
        dd($photo);
    }
```

In database table `photos` i have column `alias`:
[image]

Why when I go by url-address **admin/photos/alias1/edit** laravel 5.6 does not automatically load the model Photo in which the alias = alias1, but loads an empty model:

[image]

If in the address line instead of the parameter **alias** write id **admin/photos/1/edit** + in the route, delete the parameter name `alias`, then the Photo model is loaded normally:

[image]

But for me the parameter id does not fit, I need to use an alias Please tell me what could be the problem, and is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is used by default. This is called Implicit Route Model Binding. You need to use Explicit Route Model Binding and register alias1 to be used in a Service Provider. Check it out here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#explicit-binding

Customizing The Resolution Logic is the section you want.